# Missing line when reading using input stream reader

Tags: java, runtime

I have a sample EXE which prints below output.

**EXEs Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
Failed
```

**equivalent code in java:**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
     System.out.println(i);
}
System.out.println("Failed");
```

When trying to initiate the EXE using java code and read the output some data goes missing.

Find the java for initiating the asset.

**Java Code:**

```
String[] commands = new String[] {"sample.exe" };
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while  ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = br.readLine()
    System.out.println(line);
    if(line.toLowerCase().contains("failed")){
           #Apply business Rule.
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
3
5
```

From above output it is clear that we are missing data like `2,3,5,failed`.

I think the asset gets completed before we read using `InputStreamReader`. Is there any way we can make the asset wait till we read using `InputStreamReader` and begin the next set of instruction or is there any other more better way to do this.

**Edit1:**

In my original code I am also reading the error stream in parallel please find the code.

**ErrorStreamReader:**

```
public void run () {
    try {

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr); 
        while (true) {
                String s = br.readLine ();
                System.out.println(s+"error Stream");
                if (s == null) break;
            }

    is.close ();    
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println ("Problem reading stream " + name + "... :" + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

**EXE executer java code:**

```
String[] commands = new String[] {"sample.exe" };
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
Thread errorStream = new Thread(new ReadStream("stderr", 
    p.getErrorStream ()) # Reads error Stream In parallel
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while  ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = br.readLine()
    System.out.println(line);
    if(line.toLowerCase().contains("failed")){
           #Apply business Rule.
    }
}
```

It looks like the input stream reader is reading by skipping one line at a time.

**EDIT2:**

Since I was under the thought that `InputStreamReader` was missing even number lines I made a change in the EXE (a python script) to print from `1` to `6` and then failed.

**Modified EXE Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
Failed
```

Now the InputStreamReader output was

**Java Output:**

```
1
3
5
Failed
```

As I thought I am missing odd numbered lines. Could somebody please let me know the cause?.

---

**Note:**

> The problem was due to reading the inputStream Twice sorry for the
>   inconvenience caused. I am extremely sorry.

Comment: seems you are looking in wrong direction.. the code looks fine and should work for what you have described. the sample.exe would be returning that way .. what you see.

Comment: This looks like your exe file only prints 1 and 4.

Comment: This could be helpful http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2

Comment: @f1sh when I ran the exe through command prompt it print `1,2,3,4,5,failed` and not 1 and 4 alone

Comment: @mtk I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate what you are saying. Thanks

Comment: Could it be, that your exe prints 2,3,5 and "Failed" on the error stream and not on the Standard output stream? (Try p.getErrorStream() instead p.getInputStream()). Also, if the last message, which is "Failed" is NOT terminated with CR/LF by your exe, br.readLine() might not return it unless the stream is closed.

Comment: @ThomasPhilipp the sample exe prints every thing in standard output stream but the 'failed' is not terminated with CR/LF. Could I know the reason why it should be terminated with CR/LF?.

Comment: @The6TheSense: If the stream is not closed, the BufferedReader cannot decide, if the line is really at an end, if there is no CFLF. So the BuffereReader will wait for either more characters to spawn in the stream or for the closing of the stream.

Comment: @ThomasPhilipp the stream is closed I made a little change in the EXE and found another thing. Please look in the edit

Comment: Please provide also the code of a simple python script with which the issues can be reproduced

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I found the issue it was due to reading line twice inside the actual code. Sorry for the inconvinence caused.

Comment: @The6thSense Maybe you could add an answer yourself and accept it, this will show everybody the question is closed.

Comment: @The6thSense Maybe you could post the real code which contains the error, and then post the corrected code as the answer?

Comment: Thanks gouys will do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was due to reading the inputStream twice

```
while  ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = br.readLine() # input stream read here twice
    System.out.println(line);
    if(line.toLowerCase().contains("failed")){
           #Apply business Rule.
    }
}
```

Hence the problem. To solve it I only read inputStream once.

```
while  ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    if(line.toLowerCase().contains("failed")){
           #Apply business Rule.
    }
}
```